# Responsive Fixed Header with CSS

Tags: html, css, header, fixed

I am very new to CSS, so excuse my naive mistakes.

**Goal:** Trying to make a simple and responsive layout. I am able to make the **#container** and **#content** responsive, but the fixed **#header** remains in-place and overflows when resizing the browser window. If you resize the browser window by pushing it to the left, you will see what I am talking about.

Also, side question: If I were to add an Image in the header, would the same (potential) solution apply? If you're curious about this kind of lay-out, I am trying to edit my "Tumblr" layout and I want to make it responsive (it's a private tumblr blog that I experiment on, I am not trying to make it responsive on cell phones / tablets – yet.)

Here is this **JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/yrbvw473/2/

```
    HTML
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">This Is The Header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
        <div class="post">A</div>
    </div>
</div>


    CSS
    #container {
    border: 0px solid;
    max-width: 640px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
    #header {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 640px;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
    #content {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
    .post {
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Thank you for all the help! Again, I am new too this...**

Answer (score 1):

Comment or remove this `position: fixed;` on #header.   And change width to `max-width: 563px;`

Comment: This did not work. The header needs to be fixed, because I need it to slide over the "post." Max-width will not work either, it will default to the actual width of the text.

Comment: Then try this instead of code width:100%; max-width:642px;

Answer (score 0):

bcause u put the value of header width, that's why the header cannot flexible following browser width. use `width:100%` instead
[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6L31u8f/2/)

Comment: Does not work. If I do `width: 100%;` it will not center the the header within the container.